# In a metric space, is every convergent sequence bounded?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^p$, this is true, but is it true in every metric space?
I suppose not, but what other condition would I have to put on the metric space in order for it to have this property?

For clarity, a bounded subset $W$ of a metric space $V,d$ is a subset of $W$ with this property:
$$\exists M\in\mathbb{R}_0^+,\forall v,w \in V:\ d(v,w) < M$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it’s true in every metric space. In fact, a stronger statement is true: every Cauchy sequence is bounded. Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$. Since the sequence is Cauchy, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_k,x_\ell)<1$ whenever $k,\ell\ge m$. In particular, $d(x_m,x_n)<1$ for all $n\ge m$. Now let $\alpha=\max\{d(x_m,x_n):n<m\}$; then $d(x_n,x_m)<\alpha+1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so the sequence is bounded.

**Added:** Specifically, for all $k,\ell\in\Bbb N$ we have

$$d(x_k,x_\ell)\le d(x_k,x_m)+d(x_m,x_\ell)<2\alpha+2\;.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be even better if you included the bound. I suppose it is $2\alpha +2$?

Comment: @Syd: You're welcome. Yes, since every term is less than $\alpha+1$ from $x_m$, it follows immediately from the triangle inequality that $d(x_k,x_\ell)<2\alpha+2$ for all $k,\ell\in\Bbb N$. It honestly didn't occur to me that this needed to be made explicit.

Comment: As an 'intro to analysis' _student_, just about everything needs to be made explicit for me. I have almost no intuïtion nor any experience with this matterial.